# How to use event.value == 'CLICK_DRAG'?

Tags: python

I wonder how to use `event.value == 'CLICK_DRAG'` in a modal operator.

I tried

```
if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE' and event.value == 'CLICK_DRAG':
    print((event.mouse_x - event.mouse_prev_x), (event.mouse_y - event.mouse_prev_y))
```

but it doesn't print anything

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html

Comment: shouldn't it be `event.type = 'MOUSEMOVE'` ?

Comment: I too am trying to get click and drag events. @Gorgious I have tried stacking a `if event.type = 'MOUSEMOVE'` into a `if event.type == "LEFTMOUSE"` but the mouse move is not recognized. Any suggestions?

```if event.type == "LEFTMOUSE": 
     if event.value == "PRESS":
         if event.type == "MOUSEMOVE":
             print("mouse value", event.value)
```

Comment: Apologies for the badly formatted comment above :P Hopefully you can decipher it.

Comment: @Psyonic if my understanding is right each event fires up the modal operator, and an event can only be of one type, so the second `if event.type` can't evaluate to `True` if the first one already evaluates to `True`